# Log into a website using Python Requests

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to log into a website with Python3 using Requests library.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests#downloads

The form from the web page is as following:

```
<form action="http://www.usf.fr/connexion.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="header-extranet">
<p>
    <a href="/contact.php" class="link">Contact</a>
    <input type="text" name="login" value="Identifiant" class="clearfield text" />
    <input type="password" name="password" class="password text" />
    <input type="text" value="Mot de passe" class="password-clear text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Se connecter" class="img-txt submit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="828e0013b8f3bc1bb22b4f57172b019d" />
    <br />
    <a href="/mot-de-passe-perdu.php" class="forget">Mot de passe oubli&eacute;</a>
</p>
</form>
```

I am doing as following in Python to log into the website and then go to a specific page.

```
with requests.Session() as c:
    url = "http://www.usf.fr/connexion.php"
    USERNAME = 'MYUSERNAME'
    PASSWORD = 'MYPASSWORD'
    c.get(url)
    login_data = dict(login=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD, next='/')
    c.post(url, data=login_data, headers={"Referer": "http://www.usf.fr/connexion.php"})
    page = c.get('http://www.usf.fr/detail-membre.php?userId=0600')
    s = page.content
```

I am then writing the html of the page in a file.txt, but as a result I am not connected and can't get the information I am looking for.

When I manually log in and look in Chrome's DevTools -> Network -> connexion.php (method POST) -> Headers -> Form Data, I can see :

```
login: "MYUSERNAME"
password: "MYPASSWORD"
submit: Se connecter
redirect:
```

What am I doing wrong ? 
It seems to work with the few examples I have seen, and I can't understand how my case is different.

I thank you for your answer and your help

Tim

Comment: At least you are not passing `submit` and `redirect` parameters.